# Angular 2 Modal Error

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

Im trying to use a simple Modal in Angular 2, one that i can use in any page without the need to add a HTML tag, as i want to keep my .htmls clean. I was thinking of something like the Modal from bootstrap in Angular JS, but i wasnt able to find nothing like that.
I tryed to use [ngx-modialog](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog) but im having the following error:

```
MatchesComponent.html:37 ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__.E.create is not a function
    at DOMOverlayRenderer.webpackJsonp.../../../../ngx-modialog/bundle/ngx-modialog.es5.js.DOMOverlayRenderer.render (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59597:87)
    at Overlay.webpackJsonp.../../../../ngx-modialog/bundle/ngx-modialog.es5.js.Overlay.createOverlay (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59555:48)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59537:47
    at Array.map (native)
    at Overlay.webpackJsonp.../../../../ngx-modialog/bundle/ngx-modialog.es5.js.Overlay.open (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59537:14)
    at Modal$$1.webpackJsonp.../../../../ngx-modialog/bundle/ngx-modialog.es5.js.Modal.open (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:59670:53)
    at OneButtonPresetBuilder.webpackJsonp.../../../../ngx-modialog/bundle/ngx-modialog.es5.js.ModalOpenContextBuilder.open (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:60002:30)
    at MatchesComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/components/matches/matches.component.ts.MatchesComponent.viewItemInfo (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:801:14)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/MatchesComponent.ngfactory.js:61:27)
```

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-modialog';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AlertsComponent } from './components/alerts/alerts.component';
import { MatchesComponent } from './components/matches/matches.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './components/products/products.component';
import { ShipmentsComponent } from './components/shipments/shipments.component';
import { ComplaintsComponent } from './components/complaints/complaints.component';
import { UsersComponent} from './components/users/users.component';
import { StatisticsComponent } from './components/statistics/statistics.component';
import { BillingComponent } from './components/billing/billing.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './components/notifications/notifications.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './components/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'alerts', component: AlertsComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'matches', component: MatchesComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'shipments', component: ShipmentsComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'complaints', component: ComplaintsComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'statistics', component: StatisticsComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'billing', component: BillingComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    AlertsComponent,
    MatchesComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    ShipmentsComponent,
    ComplaintsComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    StatisticsComponent,
    BillingComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
    PagenotfoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ModalModule,
    BootstrapModalModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
    )
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

matches.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { TableComponent } from '../alerts/alerts.component';
import { Modal } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';

import * as _ from 'lodash';

export class ItemsResult {
  data: [Object];
  total: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-matches',
  templateUrl: './matches.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matches.component.less'],
  providers: [ ApiService , AuthService ]
})
export class MatchesComponent {

  tableHeaders: TableComponent[] = [
    { name: 'ID', attribute: '_id' },
    { name: 'Fecha de Expiración', attribute: 'expire_at' },
    { name: 'Item ID', attribute: 'item_id' },
    { name: 'Nombre Item', attribute: 'item_title'},
    { name: 'Order ID', attribute: 'order_id' },
    { name: 'Nombre Order', attribute: 'order_title' },
    { name: 'Stock', attribute: 'stock' },
    { name: 'Ver Order', attribute: '' }
  ];

  filterOptions: TableComponent[] = [
    { name: 'ID', attribute: '_id' },
    { name: 'Item ID', attribute: 'item_id' },
    { name: 'Nombre Item', attribute: 'item_title' },
    { name: 'Order ID', attribute: 'order_id' },
    { name: 'Nombre Order', attribute: 'order_title' }
  ];

  actualPage = 0;
  filteredList;
  total;
  sorted = false;
  filterType = this.filterOptions[0].attribute;
  filterValue = '';

  constructor( public apiService: ApiService, public auth: AuthService, public modal: Modal ) {
    this.updateMatches();
  }

  updateMatches(): void {
    this.apiService.getMatchesForPage(this.actualPage, '', this.filterType, this.filterValue).then((result: ItemsResult) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.total = result.total;
      this.filteredList = result.data;
    });
  }

  changePageUp(): void {
    const limit = this.total / 100;
    if (this.actualPage < limit) {
      this.actualPage++;
    }
    this.updateMatches();
  }

  changePageDown(): void {
    if (this.actualPage > 0) {
      this.actualPage--;
    }
    this.updateMatches();
  }

  sortBy(attribute: string): void {
    if (this.sorted) {
      this.filteredList = _.orderBy(this.filteredList, [attribute], ['asc']);
    } else {
      this.filteredList = _.orderBy(this.filteredList, [attribute], ['desc']);
    }
    this.sorted = !this.sorted;
  }

  viewItemInfo(itemId): void {
    this.modal.alert()
      .size('lg')
      .showClose(true)
      .title('A simple Alert style modal window')
      .body(`
            <h4>Alert is a classic (title/body/footer) 1 button modal window that 
            does not block.</h4>
            <b>Configuration:</b>
            <ul>
                <li>Non blocking (click anywhere outside to dismiss)</li>
                <li>Size large</li>
                <li>Dismissed with default keyboard key (ESC)</li>
                <li>Close wth button click</li>
                <li>HTML content</li>
            </ul>`)
      .open();

  }

  viewOrderInfo(orderId): void {

  }

}
```

Im guessing the error is not due to the modal module but im missing some dependency, but i can't figure out which one, any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Can you show your component code where you use the modal, and also your app module definition?

Comment: Done, thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had literally the same error today. I was trying to implement a custom modal window with a component. I tried it with ngx-modialog and the error appeared. After testing it with a older version (angular2-modal 3.0.2 instead of ngx-modialog) and typescript version 2.3.4 the error disappeared.

Comment: This fixed the error, but now the modal shows and its transparent o.O, i dont know why....

Comment: Already Fixed the problem completelly, i had to include Bootstrap in Styles and JQuery in Scripts, that solved the transparent problem.

Answer (score 0):

In you app.module, try calling .forRoot() when you are importing the ModalModule:
(as per the [ngx-modialog quickstart docs](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ngx-modialog) )

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(), //instead of just ModalModule
    BootstrapModalModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
    )
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with Modals A LOT, i finally decided to make my own modal, and i think is quite better than the ones i found out there as it receives parameters and can include any HTML in its body, i leave it here for people with this problem to use it. The requeriments are the following:

- [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)
- [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#package-managers)
- [JQuery](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to)

Do not forget to include bootstrap.min.css in styles and jquery.min.js in scripts.

After this is done, you should include bootstrap in your app.module.ts:

```
...
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ]
...
```

Then you can use the component i have created like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { isUndefined } from 'util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-modal',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" [innerHTML]="bodyHTML">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="successFunction()">{{okButtonText}}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="cancelFunction()">{{cancelButtonText}}</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./custom-modal.component.less']
})

export class CustomModalComponent {

  title;
  bodyHTML;
  okButtonText = 'Aceptar';
  cancelButtonText = 'Cerrar';
  successCallback;
  cancelCallback;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}

  successFunction() {
    this.activeModal.close('Close click');
    if (!isUndefined(this.successCallback)) {
      this.successCallback();
    }
  }

  cancelFunction() {
    this.activeModal.close('Close click');
    if (!isUndefined(this.cancelCallback)) {
      this.cancelCallback();
    }
  }

}
```

Usage example:

```
...
constructor( private modalService: NgbModal  ) {}
...
sendNotification() {
    //send notification...
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(CustomModalComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = 'Notification Sent';
    modalRef.componentInstance.bodyHTML = '<p>Notification Succesfully sent.</p>';
  }
```

This modal was made by me, it works and its fully customizable, feel free to change it as you need. Hope it helps someone!

Regards,